# How to get returned data from a function in react.js after promise

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
import html2canvas from 'html2canvas';

export default function htmlToImg(id) {
    applyShadow(false);
    html2canvas(document.getElementById(id),{scale:1})
    .then(canvas => {
         applyShadow(true);
        let img = canvas.toDataURL('image/png')
        return img
    });
}



let img = htmlToImg(id)
console.log(img)
```

Here i shared my code.

I am trying to get data from **htmlToImg(id)** by passing id argument to that **function**.
Basically that function is converting **html nodes** to **image** and returning back.

THe problem is when i am printing it inside **htmlToImg()** function it is working fine but, when i am printing after calling that function
it is sometimes giving **undefined** and sometimes giving **half of hashed image data.**

Basically the html node big so sometimes it is **returning half of the image**.

I wants it to return after everything is done.

Please have a look

Answer (score 1):

Your function is asynchronous plus you are not returning anything. So it will give you `undefined`. You need to return the promise from the function and then access the value of img after the promise is resolved

```
import html2canvas from 'html2canvas';

export default function htmlToImg(id) {
    applyShadow(false);
    return html2canvas(document.getElementById(id),{scale:1})
    .then(canvas => {
         applyShadow(true);
        let img = canvas.toDataURL('image/png')
        return img
    });
}



htmlToImg(id).then(img => {
console.log(img)
})
```

Comment: Hi Moinul, Thanks for answer. If the function will take 1 minute also it will work right ?

Comment: ya it should technically